# How to move a dynamically created button?

Tags: asp.net

I have a Button1 and a textbox. When i put a value in textbox and click this button then a new button is created with the value filled in textbox but i want that when again i click Button1 and there should be one more button or we can say how to move previous button's position?

This is code for Button1 in .aspx.cs

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        Button btnNew = new Button();
        btnNew.ID = "btnNew";
        btnNew.Text = textBox1.Text;

        form1.Controls.Add(btnNew);
    }
```

Please help me to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to use javascript. Please post some code and give more detail, because your question is not very clear.

Comment: That is not MVC. Please remove the asp.net-mvc tag from this post.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something like this with JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#button2').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#button2').css('top', '50px');
});
```

etc. You should provide more info as suggested by Matt.

Comment: Could u please explain your comment?

Comment: The point here is to do it with JavaScript. Either you add two buttons and show the first on the first click and the other on the second click. Or you change the position of the button like in the example above. Add other style attributes like left and top to decide the position of the button.

Comment: I don't like the solution where you change the location of the button that much. I would go with two buttons I think.